# change color when a country selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-selectors

I am trying to change color of a telephone field when a country is selected on the `<select>` options.

For example if someone selects UK the color must change to Red.

But I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. This doesn't change at the moment.

```js
jQuery('select[name="address[_item1][country_id]"]').change(function() {
  if (jQuery(this).val() == 'GB') {
    jQuery('#_item1telephone').css("background-color", "yellow");
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select class=" required-entry countries required-entry select" name="address[_item1][country_id]" id="_item1country_id">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="GB">Uruguay</option>
</select>
<input type="text" class=" required-entry input-text required-entry" value="" name="address[_item1][telephone]" id="_item1telephone">
```

Comment: You have an extra `)` in your if's ending `})`. http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/vxrwLovm/

Comment: Syntax error... remove extra ")" in the `IF` statment

Comment: Works fine once the syntax is fixed. http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/vx5ume5t/

Comment: also do you have to use `[` `]` in the name? that will probably cause problems.

Comment: The lesson here is that your first stop should be the browser console. It was spelled out pretty plainly there.

Comment: @sdcr - Why would that cause problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had an extraneous parens after the IF statement.  This code works fine:

```
jQuery('select[name="address[_item1][country_id]"]').change(function() {
  if (jQuery(this).val() == 'GB') {
    jQuery('#_item1telephone').css("background-color", "yellow");
  } // <== here
});
```

<kbd>[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/o8t2cmy3/)</kbd>